# How to Validate the timepicker as from time to time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i need to validate the time picker from time and to time for example http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-range.html in this page they can validate the from date and to date but this is for date-picker like that i need to do for time-picker and i need to give at-least 1 hour different between from and to time. My code is not working please some one help me friends. .

```
    $('#Stime').timepicker({
         controlType: 'select',
         stepMinute: 15,
         timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
         onClose: function (time) {
               $("#Etime").timepicker("option", "maxTime", time);
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, there is no timepicker object in jQueryUI as far as I know.
However, there are many plugins out there you can actually try.